# Array initialization inside function

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, initialization

When I execute the following code it does its job well, but if I put the `int a[16][16];` expression inside the `main` function , it just randomly outputs some number when executed. What is the cause?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a[16][16];

int main(void){
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
        a[i][0] = 1;
    a[1][1] = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= 15; i++)
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            a[i][j] = a[i - 1][j] + a[i - 1][j - 1];
    cout<<(a[15][7]);
}
```

Comment: Static variables are zero initialized, not in `functions` as `main`

Comment: *but if ı carry the int a[16][16]; expression insiide main function* -- What warning(s) did your compiler have when you did this?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it gives (0xc0000142) error code and as output some random numbers

Comment: No, when you compiled your code, what warnings did the compiler give you?  Diudn't it warn you that the variable is being used without being initialized?

Comment: @Jarod42 what do you mean by static variables and if it wasnt static would it work inside function

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no

Comment: @34MFB34 -- Variables that are not global or static are not initialized.  By placing the array inside of `main`, the entire array contains values that are indeterminate.

Comment: When declared as global, `a` is filled with 0. declared in main, it has garbage value (and reading from them is even UB).

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static/global variables are zero initialized.

In functions uninitialized variables stay aren't (zero) initialized.

Reading uninitialized value is undefined behavior (UB).

Running your code, we have:

```
for (int i = 1; i != 16; ++i) a[i][0] = 1
a[1][1] = 1
a[2][1] = a[1][1] + a[1][0];
a[2][2] = a[1][2] + a[1][1]; // Access a[1][2] not initialized yet
```

You might solve your issue by initialisation

```
int a[16][16]{}; // All zeros
```